# How to pass a list of variable conditions to a filter function, instead of a single condition, in python?

Tags: python, nested-lists, filterfunction

I want to filter a list of lists passing variable set of conditions but not one by one. Is there any way to pass a whole list of conditions to the filter function and extract the desired list of values based on condition?
Here is my code:

```
profiles = [
    ['Rose Winds', 'Cloud Computing', 'USA', 6.5, 5000, 5, 'F'],
    ['Merry Brown', 'Cloud Computing', 'UK', 5, 7000, 5, 'F'],
    ['Abdul Fazil', 'Big Data', 'Australia', 11, 8000, 4, 'M'],
    ['Chris Janes', 'Big Data', 'Ireland', 7, 2500, 4, 'M'],
    ['Lina Mesro', 'Cyber Security', 'Malaysia', 7, 6500, 4, 'F'],
    ['Sireen May', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'Australia', 0, 4000, 4, 'F'],
    ['Jine Tims', 'Robotics', 'Australia', 0, 3500, 3, 'M'],
    ['Niki Rohdes', 'Artificial Intelligence', 'China', 9, 8500, 5, 'F']
]

europe = ["UK", "Ireland", "Germany", "Scotland"]


def from_europe():
    ls = []
    for profile in profiles:
        for country in europe:
            if country in profile:
                ls.append(country)
    return ls


def make_conditions(**kwargs):
    fields = {
        'name': 0,
        'specialization': 1,
        'country': 2,
        'experience': 3,
        'salary': 4,
        'qualification': 5,
        'gender': 6
    }

    def filter_func(elt):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if elt[fields[k]] != v:
                return False
            else:
                return True
    return filter_func


result = list(filter(make_conditions(country=from_europe()), profiles))
print(result)
```

When I give condition like `country='UK'` etc, then it works properly but when I try to pass a list of conditions like `country=["UK", "Ireland", "Germany", "Scotland"]`, then it give me an empty list...
Anyone help me please??

Comment: If you have the chance of using `pandas` you can filter as you want without writing a line of code. Try with the `groupy` function

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
[p for p in profiles if p[fields['country']] in europe]
```

Note: for faster processing, make `europe` a `set` instead of a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a list `country=["UK", "Ireland", "Germany", "Scotland"]`

```
if elt[fields[k]] != v
```

becomes

```
if 'USA' != ["UK", "Ireland", "Germany", "Scotland"]
```

I would do something like:

```
if isinstance(v, str) and elt[fields[k]] == v:
    return True
elif elt[fields[k]] in v:
    return True
else:
    return False # prefer to return 'False' by default
```

Then run

```
result = list(filter(make_conditions(country=europe), profiles))
# [['Merry Brown', 'Cloud Computing', 'UK', 5, 7000, 5, 'F'], ['Chris Janes', 'Big Data', 'Ireland', 7, 2500, 4, 'M']]
```

If you just want to filter by `country`, the other answer is better.

Comment: Sir, It now return all the lists... i just want to extract the lists that contains those countries present in the list europe